# SQL get all rows which have the same id but different values in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
ID_a | ID_b | VAL
1    | 1    | 'a'
1    | 2    | 'b'
1    | 3    | 'a'
2    | 1    | 'a'
2    | 2    | 'c'
3    | 1    | 'c'
4    | 1    | 'c'
5    | 1    | 'b'
6    | 1    | 'e'
```

I need to perform a query, which will select all ID_a which have more than one row, but those rows have different values in the VAL column, so the result in the example would be ID_a = 1 (more than one row, VAL is in ('a', 'b')) and ID_a = 2 (more than one row, VAL is in ('a', 'c')). Is it possible to write such a query in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using HAVING  count*) and count(distintc VAL)  > 1  group by ID_a

```
select  ID_a
from my_table  
group by ID_a
having count(*)>1 
and count(distinct VAL) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `string_agg()`

```
select  ID_a,string_agg(distinct val order by val)
from my_table  
group by ID_a
having count(*)>1 
and count(distinct VAL) > 1
```

Comment: Unforunately, the string_agg function does not work in PostgreSQL the way you wrote.